# woocommerce_order_items table doesn't exist

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Please let me know how to install this table on woocommerce.

woocommerce_order_items

I deactivated and activated the plugin as well.  Wordpress prefix also not containing more than 6 characters.  If you have this table please post a SQL query to create this table manually.

WC Version: 2.4.6

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `wp_woocommerce_order_items`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_woocommerce_order_items` (
  `order_item_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_item_name` longtext NOT NULL,
  `order_item_type` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `order_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`order_item_id`),
  KEY `order_id` (`order_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=236 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: when someone order something will this table updated>